# Use Backspace Button to Focus on Previous Entry Field in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin app, on PIN Page, there are 8 Entry Fields, 4 for PIN and 4 for Confirm PIN (here I just paste 2).

When user enter a value in a field, the cursor focus on the next field and so on. But if they enter value mistakenly and wants to clear it, they can't go back to the last entry by pressing *Backspace Button*. They have to press on that entry field for focus.

Below is the Code for Entry Fields. How can I go back / focus on the last entry field by pressing Backspace button?

**.xml**

```
<Entry
    x:Name="PasswordOne"
    Text="{Binding PasswordOne}"
    IsPassword="True"
    Keyboard="Numeric"
    MaxLength="1"
    ReturnType="Next"
    TextChanged="Entry_FieldChanged" />
```

**.xml.cs**

```
public PasswordPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    entryList = new List<Entry>();
    entryList.Add(PasswordOne);
    entryList.Add(PasswordTwo);

    entryList.Add(ConfirmPasswordOne);
    entryList.Add(ConfirmPasswordTwo);
}

private void Entry_FieldChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var entry = sender as Entry;

    const string numregex = "^[0-9]+$";

    if (!(!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(entry.Text, numregex) || entry.Text == ""))
    {
        if (entry.Text.Length >= 1)
        {
            var index = entryList.IndexOf(entry);
            var nextIndex = (index + 1) >= entryList.Count ? 0 : index + 1;
            var next = entryList.ElementAt(nextIndex);
            if (entry == ConfirmPasswordTwo)
            { }
            else
            {
                next?.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var index = entryList.IndexOf(entry);
        var prevIndex = (index) == 0 ? 0 : index - 1;
        var prev = entryList.ElementAt(prevIndex);
        if (entry == PasswordOne)
        { }
        else
        {
            prev?.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

**CustomEntry.xml.cs**

```
namespace Mobile.App
{
    public class CustomEntry : Entry
    {

        public delegate void BackspaceEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

        public event BackspaceEventHandler OnBackspace;
        public CustomEntry() { }

        public void OnBackspacePressed()
        {
            OnBackspace?.Invoke(null, null);
        }

    }
}
```

**CustomEntryRenderer**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace Mobile.App.Droid
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer, IInputFilter
    {
        public CustomEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public ICharSequence FilterFormatted(ICharSequence source, int start, int end, ISpanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source.ToString()))
            {
                var entry = (CustomEntry)Element;
                entry.OnBackspacePressed();
            }
            return source;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (Control != null)
            {
                int length = Control.Text.Length;
                Control.SetSelection(length);
                SetColors();
            };

            Control.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { this });
        }

        private void SetColors()
        {
            Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        }
    }
}
```

**.xml.cs**

```
public partial class PasswordPage : ContentPage
{

    public List<Entry> entryList { get; set; }

    public PasswordPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ValidatePassword();

        entryList = new List<Entry>();
        entryList.Add(PasswordOne);
        entryList.Add(PasswordTwo);

        entryList.Add(ConfirmPasswordOne);
        entryList.Add(ConfirmPasswordTwo);
    }

    Entry entry;
    private void Entry_FieldChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        entry = sender as Entry;

        const string numregex = "^[0-9]+$";

        if (!(!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(entry.Text, numregex) || entry.Text == ""))
        {
            if (entry.Text.Length >= 1)
            {
                var index = entryList.IndexOf(entry);
                var nextIndex = (index + 1) >= entryList.Count ? 0 : index + 1;
                var next = entryList.ElementAt(nextIndex);
                if (entry == ConfirmPasswordTwo)
                { }
                else
                {
                    next?.Focus();
                }
            }
        }
        //else
        //{
        //    var index = entryList.IndexOf(entry);
        //    var prevIndex = (index) == 0 ? 0 : index - 1;
        //    var prev = entryList.ElementAt(prevIndex);
        //    if (entry == PasswordOne)
        //    { }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        prev?.Focus();
        //    }
        //}
    }

    private void CustomEntry_OnBackspace(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string numregex = "^[0-9]+$";

        if (!(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(entry.Text, numregex) || entry.Text == ""))
        {
            var last = entryList.ElementAt(entryList.Count - 1);
            last?.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**.xml**

```
<local:CustomEntry
    x:Name="PasswordOne"
    IsPassword="True"
    Keyboard="Numeric"
    MaxLength="1"
    ReturnType="Next"
    TextChanged="Entry_FieldChanged"
    OnBackspace="CustomEntry_OnBackspace"
    Unfocused="Password_Unfocused" />
```

Comment: What is your Backspace button? In the keyboard? When you press this button, do you wanna to focus on the last?

Comment: yes, yes and yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to focus to the last entry when you press the `Backspace` button, you could use the custom renderer.

Custom Entry:

```
 public class CustomEntry : Entry
{
     
    public delegate void BackspaceEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
   
    public event BackspaceEventHandler OnBackspace;
    public CustomEntry() { }

    public void OnBackspacePressed()
    {
        OnBackspace?.Invoke(null, null);
    }

}
```

Custom renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace Test.Droid
{
public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer, Android.Text.IInputFilter
{
    public CustomEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public ICharSequence FilterFormatted(ICharSequence source, int start, int end, ISpanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source.ToString()))
        {
            var entry = (CustomEntry)Element;
            entry.OnBackspacePressed();
        }
        return source;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Control.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { this });

    }

    

}
}
```

Xaml:

```
  <local:CustomEntry
            x:Name="PasswordOne"
            IsPassword="True"
            Keyboard="Numeric"
            MaxLength="1"
            OnBackspace="CustomEntry_OnBackspace"
            ReturnType="Next"
            Text="{Binding PasswordOne}"
            TextChanged="Entry_FieldChanged" />

        <local:CustomEntry
            x:Name="PasswordTwo"
            IsPassword="True"
            Keyboard="Numeric"
            MaxLength="1"
            OnBackspace="CustomEntry_OnBackspace"
            ReturnType="Next"
            Text="{Binding PasswordTwo}"
            TextChanged="Entry_FieldChanged" />

        <local:CustomEntry
            x:Name="ConfirmPasswordOne"
            IsPassword="True"
            Keyboard="Numeric"
            MaxLength="1"
            OnBackspace="CustomEntry_OnBackspace"
            ReturnType="Next"
            Text="{Binding ConfirmPasswordOne}"
            TextChanged="Entry_FieldChanged" />

        <local:CustomEntry
            x:Name="ConfirmPasswordTwo"
            IsPassword="True"
            Keyboard="Numeric"
            MaxLength="1"
            OnBackspace="CustomEntry_OnBackspace"
            ReturnType="Done"
            Text="{Binding ConfirmPasswordTwo}"
            TextChanged="Entry_FieldChanged" />
```

Code behind:

```
   public List<Entry> entryList { get; set; }
    public Page3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        entryList = new List<Entry>();
        entryList.Add(PasswordOne);
        entryList.Add(PasswordTwo);

        entryList.Add(ConfirmPasswordOne);
        entryList.Add(ConfirmPasswordTwo);
    }
    Entry entry;
    private void Entry_FieldChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        entry = sender as Entry;

        const string numregex = "^[0-9]+$";

        if (!(!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(entry.Text, numregex) || entry.Text == ""))
        {
            if (entry.Text.Length >= 1)
            {
                var index = entryList.IndexOf(entry);
                var nextIndex = (index + 1) >= entryList.Count ? 0 : index + 1;
                var next = entryList.ElementAt(nextIndex);
                if (entry == ConfirmPasswordTwo)
                { }
                else
                {
                    next?.Focus();
                }
            }
        }
        //else
        //{
        //    var index = entryList.IndexOf(entry);
        //    var prevIndex = (index) == 0 ? 0 : index - 1;
        //    var prev = entryList.ElementAt(prevIndex);
        //    if (entry == PasswordOne)
        //    { }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        prev?.Focus();
        //    }
        //}
    }

    private void CustomEntry_OnBackspace(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string numregex = "^[0-9]+$";

        if (!(!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(entry.Text, numregex) || entry.Text == ""))
        {
            var last = entryList.ElementAt(entryList.Count - 1);
            last?.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Please note that we need to comment the else part of `Entry_FieldChanged`.

**Updated:**

> On .xml.cs page I can't use Entry as a base class. It returns an error. Currently, I'm using ContentPage

Create a new class and do not use the Entry as base class directly for the ContentPage.

If you still have the error, please provide the error with the error message.

> for local:Entry, I add the xmlns:local="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" as a reference, right?

No, local is the location for `CustomEntry`. For me, the `CustomEntry` is in the Xamarin.forms project named Test.

```
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
```

> I've already an Entry Custom Renderer (Below is the code) in my project. The OnBackspacePressed(); says that Entry doens't contain the definition for OnBackspacePressed().

Do you create the custom entry first? I define the `OnBackspacePressed` in my CustomEntry control.

> without tapping/touching/clicking on entry no. 2, if u click backspace button from any entry, u just go back to previous entry, again WITHOUT tapping/clicking/touching manually on any entry

```
 private void CustomEntry_OnBackspace(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string numregex = "^[0-9]+$";

        if (!(!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(entry.Text, numregex) || entry.Text == ""))
        {
            //var last = entryList.ElementAt(entryList.Count - 1);
            //last?.Focus();
            var index = entryList.IndexOf(entry);
            var pre = entryList.ElementAt(index - 1);
            pre?.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I faced some issues, I posted them above in **Updated** section..

Comment: I have updated my reply. Please check it.

Comment: I updated the code as u said, no errors, but the backspace isn't working.. I posted my updated code above..  kindly, have a look..

Comment: ohhh, sorry. I forget to change the code in `CustomEntry_OnBackspace`. Please check it. It works now. Here is the screenshot. https://imgur.com/F9FYkZe

Comment: thanks, backspace is working... I think I wasn't clear for which I'm sorry.. I meant that if u enter wrong PIN, u just press backspace button, and u will go back to the previous (not the last entry, but the previous entry) and u can erase it..

Comment: in this code, I have to focus on entry manually (by clicking it and then erase it) and second, by erasing the text from entry, it will focus on the last (ConfirmPasswordTwo entry).

Comment: I update ur code, kindly review it.. now the only thing which I don't know, how to achieve is, that how to focus on preview entry by clicking on backspace button.. (in this code, it just go to preview entry once). but I want it to work even the entry is empty..

Comment: @Zossimov What does the `focus on preview entry by clicking on backspace button` mean? I am confused about your needs.The backspace button could triggle now and we need to focus on the logic.

Comment: if u click on backspace button, focus on previous entry...

Comment: @Zossimov Have you check the screenshot? When i click on the backspace button, focus on the last entry. https://imgur.com/F9FYkZe

Comment: yes, but I said I want to focus on previous entry by backspace not last (and it's working fine, thanks..)

Comment: but as u see, in ur screenshot, first u enter value in entry 1,2,3,4 and then u focus o entry no. 2 manually by clicking on it and when u press backspace, it focus on last entry... now what I want is that, without tapping/touching/clicking on entry no. 2, if u click backspace button from any entry, u just go back to previous entry, again WITHOUT tapping/clicking/touching manually on any entry (in ur screenshot case, u clicked on entry no. 2)..

Comment: Check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/K0dOAkb I am not sure if this is what you want. When you input into the entry, it would focus on the next entry. It is conflict.

Comment: cannot open this link

Comment: I'm talking about this.. **This site can’t be reached**

Comment: @Zossimov the site can be reached, try another internet connection